# Find the correct intermediate cert type in a list of files using python

Tags: python, ssl

I'm new into python and i want to do something like:

```
for i in $(ls -1 *.crt) ; do echo $i ; openssl x509 -noout -text -in $i | grep -i telesec ; done
```

to find out the type of intermediate certificates.

I managed to get the filelist but im not sure how to continue with that openssl command. Maybe with subprocess or OpenSSL.crypto?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import glob

def filelist():

    for filename in glob.iglob('*.crt'):
        print filename

filelist()
```

Thanks a lot your help!

Comment: Have you tried the `subprocess` version and found that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import glob

def openssl_509(path):
    rval = subprocess.check_output('openssl x509 -noout -text -in {0}'.format(path)
    return rval

def main():
    for filename in glob.iglob('*.crt'):
        text = openssl_509(filename)
        if 'telesec' in text:
            print filename

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```